# regex for decimal number validation

Tags: angularjs, regex

I am adding a validation on a text box for decimal number (4,2). i tried below code, it works after the decimal point (meaning it's restricting user inputing more than 2 digits after decimal point) but it doesn't restrict user inputing more than 4 digits before the decimal point.

`ng-pattern-restrict="^[0-9]{0,4}+(.[0-9]{0,2})?$"`

- Valid input: 10.20
- Valid input: 1234.23
- Invalid input: 123456.23
- Invalid input: 1234.23456

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `{0,4}` means "0 to 4 of the proceeding pattern". The `+` means "one or more of the proceeding pattern" and the `.` means "any character".

So it sounds like you need to drop the `+` (you already have the count specified in `{0,4}`) and escape the `.` to match the literal decimal point.

`^[0-9]{0,4}(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$`

- 10.20 matches
- 1234.23 matches
- 123456.23 no match
- 1234.23456 no match

Keep in mind this is not a universally acceptable method of validating decimals. Different regions use different symbols for the decimal point, for example.

Comment: Doesn't the the `+` mean [possessive](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#cheat_sheet) here. However no idea if modern JS supports those

Comment: Oh yes, I think you're quite right. And perhaps it's unsupported.

Comment: The above one is working thank you Health Raftery, I want to allow comma anywhere before the decimal point. Can you help me where i can add comma. Ex: 10,20,000.00

Comment: That's quite a different request. It would be irresponsible to answer it in a comment. Remember the `[]` means match any of the enclosed character sets, so you can just put a comma next to `0-9`. But that doesn't solve your longer number problem. Try out some regex and ask another question if you get stuck.